# How to do arithmetic operations in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
stage('Tagging and Pushing') { 
    def x = 1; 
    a = x + x;
    echo a;
}
```

My Question is about how to perform this operations

Comment: it is giving an error in pipeline saying `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: The echo step expects a string. What happens if you try echo "$a"? Also you don't need the semi colons.

Comment: it is working fine.., Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use print instead of echo. It will work.

```
stage('Tagging and Pushing') { 
def x = 1; 
a = x + x;
print a;
```

}

if you want to use echo you can use as below :

```
stage('Tagging and Pushing') { 
def x = 1; 
a = x + x;
echo "${a}"
}
```